# displaying django admin instead of my html

Tags: html, django

I am trying to do a password change in Django. The problem is that instead of my html template, it uses Django admin. How do I make my template go over, and not the admin?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('registration/', registration, name='registration'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='login'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/password_reset/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="password_change.html"), name='password_reset'),
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKupF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the first matching url pattern. Since you declare a url pattern of your own to replace one from `django.contrib.auth.urls` you should write it **above** those urls.

Also you give a name to included urls which doesn't make sense. Furthermore the pattern you want to replace `password_reset` should be using `PasswordResetView` (you write `PasswordChangeView`), I assume you actually want to replace `password_change`.

Also no need to include the same url patterns twice (All the urls in the `django.contrib.auth.urls` would be included when you write once anyway).

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('registration/', registration, name='registration'),
    path('accounts/password_change/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="password_change.html"), name='password_change'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```